# how to include the file with relative path?

Tags: php

there is a file directory as this:`magento\app\design\frontend\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

the another file directory as this:`magento\blog\wp-blog-header.php`

now,if i want to in view.phtml include the wp-blog-header.php.how do i do?thank you.

```
include('../../../../../../../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use document root ("`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`"). But that only applies if your app is installed as the only app in the base directory on the web server. If you are running the app in a sub directory, that you need to adjust for that. However, this will make the app less portable as you cannot change the directory easily without having to modify codes.

Based on your example, it seems that you are running Magento, with Magento, you can use "`Mage::getBaseDir`" method to get the base directory of Magento and relative the include file from that.

Comment: yes,i using it in magento. could you give me with more details.thank you

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go from root up, not all of this ../../ jazz:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path-to-include-file");
```

You sure the wordpress header is compatable with magento? Could face some horrible anomalies there.

Answer (score 1):

That would work, you just have to count the slashes to make sure it's the same as before. However, you can also create a symbolic link in your `magento\app\design\frontend\default\template\catalog\product\` directory that points to `magento\blog\wp-blog-header.php`.

`ln -s magento\blog\wp-blog-header.php wp-blog-header.php` would do the trick then you can just: `include ("wp-blog-header.php");`

You can also reference `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` in your include.